# Easy way to switch network proxy settings?

Tags: proxy, networking

I regularly use a http proxy for blocked sites here in China.

However, it slows things down in general even for unblocked sites.

Is there an easy way of switching proxy profiles?  I'd prefer not to have to go in to Network Proxy everytime, if there is.

Cheers!

Running 10.10 on an Acer netbook

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to place the Network Proxy app in your gnome panel. Just left-click and drag System->Preferences->Network Proxy and drop it on your gnome panel somewhere. Create proxy profiles in the Network Proxy application by clicking "Location->New Location" and defining each proxy profile (each of them will have a unique name in the Location drop down menu). It should then take very few clicks to switch between network proxies.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using proxy just for browsing, Foxyproxy addon for Firefox will do the job.

Answer (score 2):

Add `~/.bin/toggle-proxy` and make it executable

```
#!/bin/bash
p="org.gnome.system.proxy mode";
g=gsettings;
n="'none'";
if [ `$g get $p` == $n ];then 
    $g set $p manual;
else 
    $g set $p $n;
fi;
echo `$g get $p`
```

https://gist.github.com/iegik/d8882c0e664eb60681e3f73f29a3d641

Answer (score 1):

There's a proxy applet that can be added at the gnome panel:
http://www.andreafabrizi.it/?proxyapplet

Answer (score 0):

Another way with proxy pac is described here :
http://xmodulo.com/2012/12/how-to-set-up-proxy-auto-config-on-ubuntu-desktop.html

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.